# How to tag a vats build based on the git's branch name?

Tags: git, build, tags, azure-devops, branch

I'm using Visual Studio TEAM service for CI/CD
I like to add a tag to te builds based on the git's branch name

if ( branch name is like 'deploy/dev/*')
then build should have a tag which is "development"

so far I know I can add a tag to the current build with the following PowerShell command:

```
Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]development"
```

- it works just fine.

[image]

also, I found out the following git command will give the current branch name, but unfortunately it's not a PowerShell command

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

anyone knows, how to do it?

Comment: Why is it not a powershell command? Maybe git is not installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git commands can be executed in Powershell (just make sure git is installed on the agent machine).

But since the git repo point to detached `HEAD` during VSTS build, so you can not use the command `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to get the build branch name. Instead,  there has pre-defined variable **`$(Build.SourceBranchName)`** which record the build branch name, and you can use it directly.

Such as in below PowerShell script, to add a tag `dev` if the branch name is `deploy/dev/mydev`:

```
If ("$(Build.SourceBranchName)" -eq "deploy/dev/mydev")
{
  git tag dev
  git push origin --tags
}
```

Comment: Liu - 
Thanks for your help  - it works and fix half of my problem, I'm going to ask another question if you don't mind, here is the link to it :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231440/tag-vsts-build-regarding-branch-name