# tag VSTS build regarding branch name

Tags: git, powershell, build, tags, azure-devops

I'm using VSTS for CD/CI and I like to tag my builds (not the git branch) based on the git branch name.

I got the below PowerShell script which is tagging the VSTS builds (it's different o git tag)
:

```
If ("$(Build.SourceBranchName)" -like "master")
{Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]prod"}

If ("$(Build.SourceBranchName)" -like "deploy/dev*")
{Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]dev"}
```

so when my code branch (git) is "master" then it's supposed to tag it "prod"
which is does just fine.

but when my branch name is something like "deploy/dev/feature1", it's supposed to tag it "dev" which it doesn't, it also doesn't error!

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what is the problem, this variable only return the branch name without prefix e.g. deploy/dev/feature1 
so the solution would be to use something else that gives us the full branch name which is here:

```
If ("$(Build.SourceBranch)" -like "refs/heads/master")
{Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]prod"}

If ("$(Build.SourceBranch)" -like "refs/heads/deploy/dev*")
{Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]dev"}
```

Comment: Yes, that's problem caused by $(Build.SourceBranchName) variable (it only get the last part from `/`). And you can also cut "refs/heads/" from `$(Build.SourceBranch)`, and then compare `"$(Build.SourceBranch)".Substring(11)` with `deploy/dev*`.